# Shared hosting returns 403 for no index file. Localhost returns 404. How?

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess

**My shared hosting service returns an apache 403 error when** the user **navigates to a folder** containing **no index.php**

**My localhost returns an apache 404 error when** the user **navigates to the same folder** containing **no index.php**

My localhost apache server **currently has** the following **module disabled**:

```
#LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
```

Now I don't believe this is a problem because the server really didn't find a file thus, it should indeed return a 404.

I am curious as to how my shared hosting apache server chooses to return a 403 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how my shared hosting apache server chooses to return a 403 error.

The 403 is triggered by mod_autoindex when formatted directory listings are **disabled** (the default) and no other response has already been served (eg. by mod_dir serving the `DirectoryIndex` / index document). The 403 is perhaps seen as the more appropriate response in this instance (rather than a 404), since the module is loaded/enabled but the option to actually display the directory listing is explicitly disabled.

If mod_autoindex is not loaded then the request falls through to a 404.

What you are seeing is expected/default Apache behaviour. mod_autoindex is loaded by default.